# How To Get Responsiveness In Self Made HTML & CSS WebPage

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've made a Register template with HTML & CSS. But It isn't responsive at all.

It gets very weird when I try to decrease the browser width, like this.
This Gets Turned into That:

[image: Web Page Image]
[image: Web Page Image]

My HTML Code:

```
<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href = "register.css">
    <div id="login-box">
        <div class="left-box">
                <h1>Register</h1>
                <form action="#" method="post">
                    <input type="text" class="txtb" placeholder="Username">
                    <input type="text" class="txtb" placeholder="Email">
                    <input type="text" class="txtb" placeholder="Password">
                    <input type="text" class="txtb" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" name="signup-button" class="signup-btn">
                </form>
                <small class="text-muted ">Already Have An Account?<a href="#">Login</a></small>
        </div>
        <div class="right-box">
        </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS Code:

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #777;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    background-image: url(images/image.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

#login-box
{
    position: relative;
    height: 430px;
    width: 630px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    transform: translate(45%, 14%);
}

.left-box
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 430px;
}

h1
{
    margin: -10px 0 20px 0;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 28px;
}

input.txtb
{
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 34px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
}

input[type="submit"]
{
  height: 32px;
  width: 47%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 44px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.6s;
  border-style: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-20deg, #fc6076 0%, #ff9a44 100%);
  color: white;
}


input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:focus
{
  transform: scale(1.04);
}

.right-box
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 315px;
    height: 430px;
    background-image: url(images/bg.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}


small a
{
    margin-left: 4px; 
}


small a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes autofill {
    to {
        color: black;
        background: transparent;
    }
}

.txtb:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-animation-name: autofill;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

How Can I Avoid this and set a limit to screen minimize or just show something else when the browser width is decreased?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: do you have a doctype or any viewport meta tags?

Comment: You can check out the flex box (display:flex),  https://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/ and add media queries

Comment: @imjared I don't but what does those tags do?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to put a media query within your css declaration.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

This example will give any device, that is 600px wide or less, a lightblue background.

Comment: Thanks! Can I change all the design of the website using this?

Comment: @Heisenberg Yes, you can change everything with a media query.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Bootstrap? it's not that hard, it works great and theres a lot of documentation online and people on SO that can help you too. Here's a link to get you started: https://getbootstrap.com/

In a nutshell, bootstrap is a tool that helps you make simple websites responsive so they can scale between devices. In actuality it's a little more complcated than this but nothing to worry about.

Comment: Actually, I am using bootstrap for the navbar but except for that do I need to use bootstrap classes in order to make my registration box responsive?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap for the navbar, so why it didn't made my page responsive?

Comment: Because the way bootstrap works is making items (eg divs) responsive (making them change size depending on the current screen-size. So, if you forget to make some part responsive, for example a text box, the rest of the website will react to the screen-size change (assuming you used bootstrap to make it responsive) but this text box will remain the same. In your example, youve made the navbar responsive making it scale depending on the screen, by the rest of the website isn't coded like that so it doesn't change size, alignment etc.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the information, Do you know how can I just make the box responsive without adding any of bootstrap's CSS?

Comment: @Heisenberg You would do that by targeting that specific box with the media query I put above in the example.